# Using Binutils Build on Solaris 10 Fails

Tags: gcc, runtime-error, ld, binutils, solaris-10

I have successfully built and installed latest binutils-2.22 on Solaris 10.

But when I try to use the installed programs such as `ld` and `or` I get a run-time error:

```
ld.so.1: ld: fatal: relocation error: file /home/pernord/alt/bin/ld: symbol __clz_tab: referenced symbol not found
```

I have search extensively for the error but all the hits seems unrelated to my problem.

From what I have read `__clz_tab` seems related to 'libgcc`.

At least libgcc contains the symbol `clz`.

```
strings /lib/*/libgcc* | grep clz
```

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3):

`__clz_tab` is a table in libgcc used to implement a CLZ ("count leading zeros") function.

Do your binutils executables depend on `libgcc_s.so`? What does `ldd /home/pernord/alt/bin/ld` show?

If `libgcc_s.so` isn't in your library search path you might need to use `crle(1)` to add it.

Comment: If I want to compile latest versions for the whole suite of GNU tools, typically binutils and gcc with all its deps, is it better to compile it all in a single pass by linking in binutils into the gcc tree and make binutils use the latest version of libgcc?

Comment: A "combined tree" build that builds everything together is only likely to work for _very_ latest development sources from cvs (for binutils) and svn (for gcc). If you want to build released versions (e.g. binutils 2.22 and GCC 4.7.1) not development snapshots then the best way is to build and install binutils first, then install gcc to the same location (i.e. with the same `--prefix` option.) GCC will automatically pick up binutils tools if they already exist at its `prefix` and will use them.